# Change border height on button click in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want the border to increase, every time I press a button.

When the button is pressed, its 'value' is increased by 1. I want the value of the pixel-height of the border of the container to increase as well.

```js
var i = 0;
var heightOfBorder = document.getElementById('test').style;

function buttonClick() {
  document.getElementById('incrementValue').value = i++
    heightOfBorder = "height: 500px";;
}




// document.getElementById("test").style.height =  document.getElementById('incrementValue').value;
```

```css
#test {
  margin-top: 200px;
  border: solid black;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Container size change</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js" integrity="sha256-r/AaFHrszJtwpe+tHyNi/XCfMxYpbsRg2Uqn0x3s2zc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="main" class="container">


    <div id="test" class="container" style="height: 50px;">

    </div>

    <button onclick="buttonClick()" id="incrementButton" type="button" class="btn btn-success">Success</button>

    <input id="incrementValue" type="text" name="button" value="0">


  </div>
  <script src="script.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

What am I doing wrong? I am learning to code. Also, side question, does anyone know of a good mentorship program?

Greetings!

Comment: Which part of code are you trying to increase your border?  Also, are you trying to increase the border incrementally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
    var i = 0;
    var heightOfBorder = document.getElementById('test').style;

    function buttonClick() {
        document.getElementById('incrementValue').value = i++;
        let currHgt = heightOfBorder.getPropertyValue('height');
        currHgt = +currHgt.slice(0, currHgt.length - 2);
        heightOfBorder.setProperty('height', currHgt + i + 'px');
    }
</script>
```

If you want to change height by i value.

Answer (score 1):

You can get current height of the box using offsetHeight and on click add the input value to the box's style.height and remember to add the unit at the end - in your case 'px'.
Here is an example:

```
var i = 0;
var myEl = document.querySelector('#test');
var initialHeight = myEl.offsetHeight;

function buttonClick() {
    document.getElementById('incrementValue').value = i++;
    myEl.style.height = initialHeight + i + 'px';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just change var 
heightOfBorder = document.getElementById('test').style;
to 
var heightOfBorder = document.getElementById('test');
and 
eightOfBorder = "height: 500px";
to 
eightOfBorder.style = "height: 500px";

```js
var i = 0;
var heightOfBorder = document.getElementById('test');

function buttonClick() {
  document.getElementById('incrementValue').value = i++
    heightOfBorder.style = "height: 500px";
}




// document.getElementById("test").style.height =  document.getElementById('incrementValue').value;
```

```css
#test {
  margin-top: 200px;
  border: solid black;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Container size change</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js" integrity="sha256-r/AaFHrszJtwpe+tHyNi/XCfMxYpbsRg2Uqn0x3s2zc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="main" class="container">


    <div id="test" class="container" style="height: 50px;">

    </div>

    <button onclick="buttonClick()" id="incrementButton" type="button" class="btn btn-success">Success</button>

    <input id="incrementValue" type="text" name="button" value="0">


  </div>
  <script src="script.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>

</html>
```